# How to return a value from batch file to my C# code

Tags: c#, sql, batch-file, c#-4.0

I have a batch file which i run from my C# code at runtime to create a new db.

I have provided:

- Username
- DBname
- Password
- Server details

and execute a sql file inside the batch file which creates the db, This is my batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -U %2 -P %3  -i SQLScript.sql
```

I want to know how can i notify my code in case i encounter an error while trying to create a db.

Can i return a value to my c# code?

I am using the `Process.start()` method to call my batch file.
I tried using `-E -b` and then giving error level but that did not work.

Comment: reading the Process output stream is the only thing coming to my mind

Comment: Why you use sqlcmd and not direct execute your script using the SqlCommand? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado-net

Comment: @alex - So how can i find difference between the kind of value returned if the db is created successfully or if it failed?

Comment: @pablo - I used sqlcommand at first but we need to create using batch file for reusablity purpose.

Comment: Why the SQL tag? I see no SQL question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try run your script direct in C# program using the SqlCommand.

Like this

```
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

    string str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
        "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
        "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
        "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
        "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
        "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
        "SIZE = 1MB, " +
        "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
        "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try 
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
```

If you need get the script from the external file, you change to:

```
string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("SQLScript.sql");
```